# Java - How to find JavaScript generated value in a .html file and extract it?

Tags: java, html, extract

I am working on a Java program that has to retrieve a couple of values out of a HTML document where JavaScript is embedded. I already used a head-less browser to save the source of the webpage.

The format is as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window._sharedData = {"country_code": "NL", "language_code": "en", "gatekeepers": {"cc": true, "sms": true}, "show_app_install": false, "static_root": "//instagramstatic-a.akamaihd.net/h1", "platform": "web", "hostname": "www.instagram.com", "entry_data": {"FeedPage": [{"feed": {"media": {"page_info": {"has_previous_page": false, "start_cursor": "1360768377836321975", "end_cursor": "KKsBARIAAAIgABgAEAAQAAgACAAIAAgA__79_______-______________3_____vd7_3_3___f7X_-__9f__________fv______7________f______9ke1HYuLdyUdv2FnF1__3___bn__1u___9_-___9d_W_____7_v____3__-__1f_r__b_3v_eb-_5__4___3_d_-f____X_7X77__t3HrzO1EPGYwQAFoKj3qj4VRgTMTM2MDc3MDMwMDk1MDU3ODc0NgA=", "has_next_page": true}, "nodes": [{"code": "BLia6FGhLy3", "date": 1476436253, "dimensions": {"width": 1080, "height": 1080}, "usertags": {"nodes": []}, "comments_disabled": false, "comments": {"count": 13, "page_info": {"has_previous_page": true, "start_cursor": "AQAP5jWcl57NiC9cWj78rqzBLGrlhK3cSQEitgUE9A89SCRi9mgAZR7bcVYwduyBwfEo40rs-p9UPlpv-yqs0dol-ZZN1kzswGiFDaPtau3mkyzNarvfF3lXl9YQBcX3XMg", "end_cursor": null, "has_next_page": false}, "nodes": [{"text": "OMG DE ERGSTE CLOWN VIDEOS STAAN NU OP @streetbroeders WTF DIT GAAT ECHT TE VER\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude28\ud83d\ude31\ud83d\ude28", "created_at": 1476436572.0, "id": "17854953877072546", "user": {"username": "dimitriiiiii8", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14350622_962082440562323_5463667153242685440_a.jpg", "id": "3585919439"}}, {"text": "Hij vlogt nou ook \ud83d\ude02 @puckthoonen", "created_at": 1476436665.0, "id": "17854953934072546", "user": {"username": "xyosrax", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14591971_643784482465188_2808893991515324416_a.jpg", "id": "421989269"}}, {"text": "@s.cllkk  omg ikga stuk baksana sende", "created_at": 1476437485.0, "id": "17854954273072546", "user": {"username": "s.avvrr", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14714421_1630476263911573_6235495801653559296_a.jpg", "id": "3636925067"}}, {"text": "@Kyra.louisa awww wij staan er in niet...", "created_at": 1476437614.0, "id": "17854954330072546", "user": {"username": "lailanaitabdellah", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14565128_1806486246263649_9106588324138582016_a.jpg", "id": "3921803536"}}]}, "caption": "ER STAAT EEN VLOG ONLINE !! CHECK HEMM \u2764\ufe0f\u2764\ufe0flink in bioooo en vergeet niet een blauw duimpje omhoog te doen", "likes": {"count": 863, "viewer_has_liked": false, "nodes": [{"user": {"username": "_peeettt_", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14498950_1889382917962867_1213856864219955200_a.jpg", "id": "2310846728"}}, {"user": {"username": "florian_xhofleer", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13129436_1053484581388440_1497220330_a.jpg", "id": "1509328689"}}, {"user": {"username": "opal.jc_", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14240791_332116903802213_510814450_a.jpg", "id": "459234511"}}, {"user": {"username": "kussomraaax", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14709575_153296821796627_7761089346496626688_a.jpg", "id": "701431190"}}, {"user": {"username": "samswanenberg", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13687380_1177347195637613_965407768_a.jpg", "id": "1531470592"}}, {"user": {"username": "_079nicky", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13658715_682148038601127_159337745_a.jpg", "id": "2958631733"}}, {"user": {"username": "xoxo_phartje", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14488249_694206510731451_5145437345356447744_a.jpg", "id": "621925932"}}, {"user": {"username": "lakeishacjs", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14709711_1302156743128341_5556269800650440704_a.jpg", "id": "1213887878"}}, {"user": {"username": "babsjeh_x", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13636227_1564992197143404_2071275735_a.jpg", "id": "1530416154"}}, {"user": {"username": "kussmarous", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14709477_320191241677767_540779637182038016_a.jpg", "id": "615374756"}}]}, "owner": {"username": "diiggys", "requested_by_viewer": false, "followed_by_viewer": true, "blocked_by_viewer": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13696373_125957381180534_1183915640_a.jpg", "full_name": "Naik Byusa", "has_blocked_viewer": false, "id": "34423417", "is_private": false}, "is_video": false, "id": "1360768377836321975", "display_src": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/e35/14705195_316998188673752_3401968978694766592_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTM2MDc2ODM3NzgzNjMyMTk3NQ%3D%3D.2", "location": null}, {"code": "BLiXPH-FI4g", "date": 1476434328, "video_views": 152, "video_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/14677708_1608586469435162_6167663639391109120_n.mp4", "usertags": {"nodes": []}, "comments_disabled": false, "location": null, "comments": {"count": 3, "page_info": {"has_previous_page": false, "start_cursor": null, "end_cursor": null, "has_next_page": false}, "nodes": [{"text": "@frankpost15", "created_at": 1476435031.0, "id": "17853388039128939", "user": {"username": "willemvisscher_", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13671145_282174172153406_1761302049_a.jpg", "id": "1298139695"}}, {"text": "@sharxnnn @jl_dgn", "created_at": 1476435731.0, "id": "17853388315128939", "user": {"username": "jbkri", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14368988_1710149442643660_1034759283482296320_a.jpg", "id": "2062518552"}}, {"text": "@patrickkpm", "created_at": 1476436806.0, "id": "17853388807128939", "user": {"username": "bryanassendelft", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14564857_1198678756861436_988051166245945344_a.jpg", "id": "297101893"}}]}, "caption": "Frankentek - Hakkeuh \ud83d\udd0a\ud83d\udd0a #Terror \u25cb\u25cf\u25cb https://m.soundcloud.com/teknogaatdoor/10-frankentek-hakkeuh", "likes": {"count": 42, "viewer_has_liked": false, "nodes": [{"user": {"username": "terror_donny", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13725767_268201096898595_726393479_a.jpg", "id": "835322770"}}, {"user": {"username": "baaaaaard", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12797680_1509686022674162_1688584928_a.jpg", "id": "2333839523"}}, {"user": {"username": "yaizamonllau", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14499080_351361555200467_8895706074150076416_a.jpg", "id": "1377103906"}}, {"user": {"username": "michelamishka", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14276662_1805780383002601_313546244_a.jpg", "id": "1590152764"}}, {"user": {"username": "ste.angler", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14033049_623968371105122_1595496671_a.jpg", "id": "1644435188"}}, {"user": {"username": "dr.mdma", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14350713_1621777218114615_2737118765807304704_a.jpg", "id": "2009841461"}}, {"user": {"username": "_.mottoos", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14449303_324014794620313_7098976999166705664_n.jpg", "id": "3901868365"}}, {"user": {"username": "kantholz_xo", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13767539_714935758645904_503495195_a.jpg", "id": "910174488"}}, {"user": {"username": "_marilena_6981", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14482040_784714728336686_6798367457821065216_a.jpg", "id": "429006425"}}, {"user": {"username": "gabber_4life", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14474384_1171060102973537_2717945524991819776_a.jpg", "id": "1920420455"}}]}, "owner": {"username": "terror.only", "requested_by_viewer": false, "followed_by_viewer": true, "blocked_by_viewer": false, "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12346215_1190627637631297_834405984_a.jpg", "full_name": "\ud83d\udc80 TERROR TRACKS ONLY \ud83d\udc80", "has_blocked_viewer": false, "id": "2021979402", "is_private": false}, "is_video": true, "id": "1360752231838944800", "display_src": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/e15/14736373_1597466177222408_3927176009354313728_n.jpg?ig_cache_key=MTM2MDc1MjIzMTgzODk0NDgwMA%3D%3D.2", "dimensions": {"width": 640, "height": 640}}, {"code": "BLiXgVqFAVc", "date": 1476434469, "video_views": 120, "video_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t50.2886-16/14704390_526737934192376_9131678466519859200_n.mp4", "usertags": {"nodes": []}, "comments_disabled": false, "location": null, "comments": {"count": 0, "page_info": {"has_previous_page": false, "start_cursor": null, "end_cursor": null, "has_next_page": false}, "nodes": []}, "caption": "M1dlet - I'm a Killa (Forthcoming Satan Inside) \ud83d\udd0a\ud83d\ude08\ud83d\udc4c #Early #Terror \u25cb\u25cf\u25cb https://m.soundcloud.com/m1dlet/m1dlet-im-a-killa", "likes": {"count": 34, "viewer_has_liked": false, "nodes": [{"user": {"username": "ruben_v_t", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14134704_1064829600271198_444689682_a.jpg", "id": "2713722767"}}, {"user": {"username": "ronaldvandelaar_", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13561599_1732495487030866_1552760297_a.jpg", "id": "1723429410"}}, {"user": {"username": "hardmaxi", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14499095_1172144672831249_1164011947683741696_n.jpg", "id": "1241658092"}}, {"user": {"username": "chacharka96", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14276627_752298758250722_677084893_a.jpg", "id": "1792680811"}}, {"user": {"username": "rohan__013", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13269534_879859075470140_550284467_a.jpg", "id": "622302799"}}, {"user": {"username": "natasroska", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14474443_172635103181510_839346852858953728_a.jpg", "id": "1560288211"}}, {"user": {"username": "bih_dali_aut", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13402245_1405506119748675_93650728_a.jpg", "id": "2354939415"}}, {"user": {"username": "paul_rimbaud", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/13703163_316224315390857_1107591926_a.jpg", "id": "329737397"}}, {"user": {"username": "michelamishka", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14276662_1805780383002601_313546244_a.jpg", "id": "1590152764"}}, {"user": {"username": "x_blvckout_x", "profile_pic_url": "https://scontent-ams3-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/14359449_1752725171635393_739947707468087296_a.jpg", "id":
```

What I want is to extract every "code" value so I can use this to browse to the photo's page.

FIXED:

Here is the solution:
    com.jaunt.Elements scripts = userAgent.doc.findEach("body").findEach("script");

```
                String JSon = scripts.getElement(2).innerHTML(); 

                userAgent.openJSON(JSon);
                JNode codes = userAgent.json.findEvery("code");
                System.out.println("codes: " + codes);
```

Comment: What have you tries so far? What is exactly your problem?

Comment: I think the code you've posted is incomplete, the JSON looks broken.

Comment: Html is XML. Javascript is in a specific set of tag. That give you a good way to find the Javascript code. For the rest, this depends on the code, if there is only Javascript Object, well this could be converted into JSON (could because the value must be on one line, no `;`) but this is specific

Comment: Yes the code is incomplete, but it will go on like this. The problem is I need to extract those "code" values to send them to another method of the Java program.

Comment: I tried with JSoup parser and Jaunt parser, but no succes... Now I am trying to get the individual script element and convert it to JSON and then back to a JSON parser..